# update and delete in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-delete

I have a table in a mysql DB, it contains values, start date and end date.
the values are being updated from time to time, and according to that - the end dates. the last update always have NULL in the end date. 
for example:

```
ID   |   Value   |   Start_Date   |   End_Date
 1   |    0.1    |   2015-10-01   |   2015-10-10
 2   |    0.3    |   2015-10-05   |   2015-10-12
 2   |    0.4    |   2015-10-12   |     NULL
 1   |    0.5    |   2015-10-10   |     NULL
 3   |    0.2    |   2015-10-10   |     NULL
```

Now, let's say I insert a record that has no meaning (the value remains the same as before - but the "Start_Date" is different - for ID=1):

```
ID   |   Value   |   Start_Date   |   End_Date
 1   |    0.1    |   2015-10-01   |   2015-10-10
 2   |    0.3    |   2015-10-05   |   2015-10-12
 2   |    0.4    |   2015-10-12   |     NULL
 1   |    0.5    |   2015-10-10   |   2015-10-20
 **1   |    0.5    |   2015-10-20   |     NULL**
```

I want to write a Stored Procedure that find those rows and "fix" them. for example, what I want to see after I run the SP (for ID=1):

```
ID   |   Value   |   Start_Date   |   End_Date
 1   |    0.1    |   2015-10-01   |   2015-10-10
 1   |    0.5    |   2015-10-10   |     NULL
```

Meaning, I need to delete the new row that I've inserted and update the "End_Date" at the row before to "NULL" (I have more fields - Primary keys, to compare so I could find the two rows - the problem is how to delete a certain row and update a different one)

Thank you!

Comment: What determines if a row "has a meaning" or not?

Comment: @fancyPants the same value for a row with "NULL" in the "End_Date", but a different "Start_Date"... it has no meaning because it's not really an update - the state (value) remains the same

Comment: So there will ever be just one row in the whole table that has End_Date set to NULL? Also you should add more sample data. What if there are two rows with the same value in a row but none of them has End_Date set to NULL but another later row?

Comment: Are there multiple entries with the same start_date or end_date? You have to reflect all possible cases in your sample data so the answer can be tested against it.

Comment: @fancyPants - I've edited the post a little, hope it's clearer now... but the "Start_Date" is also a primary key.

Comment: So, any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, how about the following. Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`ID` int, `Value` decimal(5,2), `Start_Date` date, `End_Date` date)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`ID`, `Value`, `Start_Date`, `End_Date`)
VALUES
    (1, 0.1, '2015-10-01', '2015-10-10'),
    (2, 0.3, '2015-10-05', '2015-10-12'),
    (2, 0.4, '2015-10-12', NULL),
    (1, 0.5, '2015-10-10', '2015-10-20'),
    (1, 0.5, '2015-10-20', NULL)
;
```

What you could do now is to create a copy of the table without data:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_t LIKE t;
```

Then insert the cleaned up version of your table:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_t
SELECT MIN(ID), MIN(Value), MIN(Start_Date)
, IF(MIN(IFNULL(End_Date, '1970-01-01')) = '1970-01-01', NULL, MIN(IFNULL(End_Date, '1970-01-01')))
FROM (
    SELECT
    t.*
    , @gn := IF(@prev_value != `Value` OR @prev_id != ID, @gn + 1 , @gn) AS group_number
    , @prev_value := `Value`
    , @prev_id := ID
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @prev_id := NULL, @gn := 0) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY Start_Date
) sq
GROUP BY group_number;
```

Note, that it would also be possible to do

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_t AS 
SELECT ...
```

but I chose the above version cause `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...`  also creates primary keys, indexes and foreign key constraints and so on just like the original table. `CREATE TABLE ... AS` does not do this.

Anyway, all you have to do then is this:

```
RENAME TABLE t TO t_backup, tmp_t TO t;
```

This will finish in no time and will also be an atomic operation, so even safe to use in production environment.

Your result set would be:

```
mysql > SELECT * FROM t;
+------+-------+------------+------------+
| ID   | Value | Start_Date | End_Date   |
+------+-------+------------+------------+
|    1 |  0.10 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-10 |
|    2 |  0.30 | 2015-10-05 | 2015-10-12 |
|    1 |  0.50 | 2015-10-10 | 2015-10-20 |
|    2 |  0.40 | 2015-10-12 | NULL       |
|    1 |  0.50 | 2015-10-20 | NULL       |
+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Here's how it works. All we are doing here is to scan the whole table and...
btw, here's a simplified version I had worked with in the beginning, that assumes you concentrate only on one `ID`. Kept it just for completeness and in case you want to play around with it. Might as well ignore it.

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MIN(Value), MIN(Start_Date)
, IF(MIN(IFNULL(End_Date, '1970-01-01')) = '1970-01-01', NULL, MIN(IFNULL(End_Date, '1970-01-01')))
FROM (
    SELECT
    t.*
    , @gn := IF(@prev != `Value`, @gn + 1 , @gn) AS group_number
    , @prev := `Value`
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @prev := NULL, @gn := 0) var_init_subquery
    WHERE
    ID = 1
    ORDER BY Start_Date
) sq
GROUP BY group_number;
```

Back to the explanation. The `SELECT` clause processes each line in it one after another. So the variables in the `IF()` condition actually hold their initialization value or the value of the previous row, because the value of the current row is assigned after the `IF()` function was processed. So all we do is to ever increment the `@gn` variable unless the value of `Value` (terrible column name) is the same and the `ID` is the same (and the start date is "the next one" (my english sucks here)). Also note, that this is why the `ORDER BY` is very important. There is no order in a relational database unless you specify it, so don't "optimize" it away.

- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) you can read more about using variables

Comment: Sorry, had to put the work on the code aside for a few days, just read it... it looks great and exactly what I need! Thank you :)